# How does EF update 'parentId' that has relationship parent-child in single table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My Model Class is:

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Parent { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> SubDepartments { get; set; }

}
```

DbContext is:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(s => s.SubDepartments)
            .WithOptional(s => s.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentId);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Getting SubDepartments:

```
public List<Department> GetSubDepartmentList()
{
    var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
    var result = dbContext.Departments.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Updating like this:

```
var result = GetSubDepartmentList();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    result.DepartmentName = "Name";
    result.ParentId = 3;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

My definitions are like this. EF is updating other fields except 'parentId'. How can i update 'parentId' ?

Comment: This is still not running code. If `result` is a list you can't have `result.DepartmentName` etc. Also, it's not clear what `GetSubDepartmentList()` does, where `db` comes from or how `result` is related to this `db`.

Comment: Does it matter how get i SubDepartments? It's clear like this.. Problem is not that.

Comment: Of course it does. If it returns data that's tracked by the context instance `db` then that make a huge difference. Also, code that clearly doesn't run inevitably means that things are left out which may be essential for answering the question. Personally, I don't answer questions if I have to guess too much.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your warnings. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you might have to query DB in the loop. Something like:

```
var result = GetSubDepartmentList();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    var department = db.Departments.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == result[i].Id);
    if(department != null)
    {
        department.DepartmentName = "Name";
        department.ParentId = 3;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```